# Sending plugins with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to send navigator plugins with AJAX, but I don't get full result:

Plugin list: Shockwave Flash. (I get just one plugin)

It has to be like this: Shockwave Flash - Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer - Native Client...

```
<script>
for (var myIndex = 0; myIndex < navigator.plugins.length; myIndex++) {
    var blabla = (navigator.plugins[myIndex].name);
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save.php',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        pluginlist: blabla,
    },
});  
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

One more thing...

When i test this script, it wroks fine.

```
<SCRIPT>
for (var myIndex=0; myIndex<navigator.plugins.length; myIndex++) {
    document.write(navigator.plugins[myIndex].name, " - ");
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to populate data in array:

```
var blabla = [];
for (var myIndex = 0; myIndex < navigator.plugins.length; myIndex++) {
    blabla.push(navigator.plugins[myIndex].name);
}
```

Right now each iteration overwrites `blabla` with the new value. Hence you are sending only one plugin name.

Comment: My result: 

Plugin list: Array

There is no plugins in my list. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What does `console.log(blabla)` outputs? It should be array of plugin names.

Comment: Yes! It is array of plugin names:

["Shockwave Flash", "Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer", "Native Client"...]

How can i send this array list of plugins to my PHP script which will save them?

Comment: You should be able to access it as `$_POST['pluginlist']`. How does POST array look like when you print it in save.php?

Comment: I found it! It was problem in file: save.php:

fwrite($fh, "<b>Plugin list:</b> ". print_r($nom21, TRUE). "<br/>");